# How to evaluate a double integral on a domain which is the intersection of two disks

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate

$$\int_D xy dx dy$$

where $D$ is the intersection of the 2 regions: $x^2 + y^2 < 4$ and $(x-1)^2+y^2 > 1$.

I have already drawn the picture of $D$, but still I do not know how to proceed.

Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: Hint, use polar.

Comment: I have modified your text in order to give it more precision. Do you agree ?

Comment: The 2nd disk is contained in the 1st one. Maybe a mistake in formulation.

Comment: @JeanMarie, with this wording the problem reduces to calculate the integral into the second circle. I understood the calculation is with $x^2+y^2<4$ and $(x-1)^2+y^2>1$!

Comment: @  Rafa Budría You are right. Can the OP confirm ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I seems it doesn't matter, the integral is zero.

Comment: @Rafa Budría Very right ! Excellent observation ! (for the OP: $(x,y) \to (x,-y)$ changes the integral into its opposite, but the domain is symmetrical with respect ot $x$ axis).